# Is left shift operator compact?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, hilbert-spaces

Let $T:l^2 \to l^2$ be $T(a_1,a_2,...)=(a_2,a_3,...)$. Is this linear operator compact. If yes, how to prove it? If no, please give an example.

I want to show that if $(a_2,a_3,...)$ has a cluster point or not. I think it is sufficient to show that if $(a_1,a_2,...)\in l^2$ , does it have a cluster point?

Comment: If $B$ denotes the unit ball of $\ell^2$, what is $T(B)$? Is it (pre)compact?

Comment: @NYRAHHH: You are not going to find a single point with a cluster point in any normed space.  You have to consider sets or sequences of elements of $\ell^2$ to make sense using the definition of compact operator.

Comment: Look at @Aweygan's suggestion for a straightforward hint that works directly from the definition.

Comment: You wrote down the left shift operator

Answer (score 10):

If $T$ were compact then the image of any bounded sequence would contain a convergent subsequence. However, you can take the sequence $x_n=(0,\dots,0,1,0,0,\dots)$ with a $1$ in the $n$th position.

Comment: This is nice as well +1

Comment: @AndresMejia Where am I making mistake by saying that $T$ is a limit of finite rank operator $T_n(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{n+1},\ldots) = (a_2,\ldots, a_{n+1},\ldots)$, which shows that $T$ is compact?

Answer (score 9):

Some quick explanations already, but here's a nice quick proof:

It is well known that $T^*$ is the right-shift operator, which is an isometry.  We see that $TT^* = I$ is not compact, which means that neither $T$ nor $T^*$ can be compact (since the compact operators are absorbing under composition).

Comment: Why do we need to mention that the left-shift is an isometry, or that it's adjoint to $T$? Is it not just enough to note that if we let $S$ be the left-shift then $TS=I$, which is not compact, so $T$ isn't either? Either way nice solution, +1

Comment: @AlexMathers I only mention it because it makes the solution more intuitive to me; $T^*$ is an isometry means that $T^{**}T^* = I$, and so on.  In particular, this generalizes to the statement that neither an isometry nor its adjoint can be compact (in an infinite dimensional Hilbert space).

Comment: +1, this is nice, I tried to think of something clever using the adjoint, but didn't manage.

Answer (score 8):

No. If $T$ were compact, [then every $ 0 \neq \lambda \in \sigma(T)$ would be an eigenvalue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theory_of_compact_operators).

On the other hand, $\sigma(T)$ is the unit disk in $\mathbb C$, but we will not need the full strength of this.
Note that $T(1, \lambda, \dots)=(\lambda, \lambda^2, \dots)$ for any $|\lambda|<1$, so that
$$\{\lambda \in \mathbb C \mid |\lambda|<1\}\subset \sigma(T),$$

and taking it closure will give the closed unit desk. Consider $\lambda=1$.

If this were an eigenvalue, then  $(a_2-a_1,a_3-a_2, \dots)=0$. But this in turn implies that $a_1=a_2=a_3, \dots$, whch is in $\ell^1$ if and only if $a_1=0$.

Comment: Well well well!

Comment: oh my, it was sheaf keef all along! Hope all is well, it looks like you got around to that functional we spoke about.